# Electron: Setting the 'fullscreen' flag to false not disabling the fullscreen button on macOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, electron, electron-vue

When creating a new `BrowserWindow` instance in Electron several flags can be set, one of which being `fullscreen`.

The description of the flag is the following:

> Whether the window should show in fullscreen. When explicitly set to false the fullscreen button will be hidden or disabled on macOS. Default is false.

However, in my experience the window simply moves to the bottom-left of the screen (notice that the button itself is green, too, rather than greyed out).

I have uploaded a GIF displaying this behaviour [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpeIA.jpg) (Stack won't let me upload a large file)

My `createWindow` declaration reads as such:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  height: 600,
  width: 600,
  title: 'Registar',
  titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
  show: false,
  resizable: false,
  fullscreen: false,
});
```

I believe that the `resizable` flag being set to false may be conflicting with `fullscreen`, somehow.

I am using the `electron-vue` boilerplate, which comes with Electron 1.7.5. Updating to 2.0.0 did *not* resolve this problem. Updating everything (disregarding my `package.json`) using `yarn upgrade --latest`.

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4.

If you want any more information please ask.

Comment: Set fullscreenable to false ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set fullscreen to false worked as expected. You can not set window to fullscreen anymore, but it is still maximizable. I think what you need is set maximizable to false.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing this. Minimizable to false definitely disables/grays the yellow button, but no combination of maximizable/fullscreen/fullscreenable to false will disable/gray the green button. This is on 10.12 Sierra... it's possible it worked on previous versions, or on later ones.

Comment: You should update the typo. It's not maxmizable, it's `maximizable`.